# SceneManager doesn't activate my previous scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm showing an inventory scene, and I do that by LoadScene Additive.
I transfer the player over to this new scene.

This also works fine. Before I load the new scene, I store a reference to the currently active scene like this:

```
private Scene PrevScene;

PrevScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
```

Now when the player exits the inventory scene by pressing a key, I thought I could simply set the previous scene to be the active scene again like this:

```
SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(UIRootObject, PrevScene); //transfer the player to the new scene
SceneManager.SetActiveScene(PrevScene);
```

However, the previous scene is not loaded. Instead the inventory scene gets brighter and brighter, so I think I'm loading the inventory scene again and again.

Is there anything fundamentally wrong with my approach or is more code needed to see what I'm doing wrong?

If yes, I've stated the entire code below:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

//First, load scene with SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync.Set allowSceneActivation to false so that the scene won't activate automatically after loading.

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject UIRootObject;
private bool _bInventoryShown = false;
private Scene PrevScene;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
    {

        Debug.Log("Is inventory currently shown: " + _bInventoryShown);

        //player pressed I to show the inventory
        if (!_bInventoryShown)
        {
            //store the currently active scene
            PrevScene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();

            //start loading the inventory scene
            StartCoroutine(loadScene("inventory"));
        }
        else
        {
            //player pressed I again to hide the inventory scene
            //so just set the previous scene as the active scene
            SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(UIRootObject, PrevScene); //transfer the player to the new scene
            SceneManager.SetActiveScene(PrevScene);
        }

        _bInventoryShown = !_bInventoryShown;
    }
}
IEnumerator loadScene(string SceneName)
{
    AsyncOperation nScene = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(SceneName, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
    nScene.allowSceneActivation = false;

    while (nScene.progress < 0.9f)
    {
        Debug.Log("Loading scene " + " [][] Progress: " + nScene.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    //Activate the Scene
    nScene.allowSceneActivation = true;

    while (!nScene.isDone)
    {
        // wait until it is really finished
        yield return null;
    }

    Scene nThisScene = SceneManager.GetSceneByName(SceneName);

    if (nThisScene.IsValid())
    {
        Debug.Log("Scene is Valid");
        SceneManager.MoveGameObjectToScene(UIRootObject, nThisScene); //transfer the player to the new scene
        SceneManager.SetActiveScene(nThisScene); //activate the scene
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Invalid scene!!");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it: I need to call SceneManager.Unload(SceneName).